# Print all permutations with repetition of characters

Tags: c++, strings, recursion, combinatorics

> Given a string of length n, print all permutation of the given string.
>   Repetition of characters is allowed. Print these permutations in
>   lexicographically sorted order

Examples:

Input: AB

Ouput: All permutations of AB with repetition are:

```
  AA
  AB
  BA
  BB
```

Input: ABC

Output: All permutations of ABC with repetition are:

```
   AAA
   AAB
   AAC
   ABA
   ...
   ...
   CCB
   CCC
```

The following is my code:

```
void permutate(const string& s, int* index, int depth, int len, int& count)
{
    if(depth == len)
    {
        ++count;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            cout << s[index[i]];
        }
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        index[depth] = i;
        permutate(s, index, depth+1, len, count);
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s("CBA");
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << "**********" << endl;
    int len = s.size();
    int* index = new int[len];
    int count = 0;
    permutate(s, index, 0, len, count);
    cout << count << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Firstly, the strings are not in lexicographically sorted order, and secondly there are repetitions - eg if `string` = "AAA", it prints "AAA" 27 times when there is really only 1 permutation. Or did I misunderstand the objective?  Also should `string s` be `const string& s` ?

Comment: @WilliamMorris, for the case "AAA", it's OK to print 27 times. You're right, the strings are not in lexicographically sorted order. I should sort the string at first. Thanks very much

Comment: Removed the C tag, as this is clearly C++.

Comment: Is the question yours, or one you have been asked? 
Are the examples yours, or given as well?

Comment: I'm leaving a comment here in case you haven't seen my answer.  I've just made a large edit to it.

Answer (score 8):

- In case you ever want to just display the string (if you have something like "AAA"):

  ```
  // if a different character from the first is not found
  // std::string::npos corresponds to "not found" (or -1)

  if (s.find_first_not_of(s.front()) == std::string::npos)
  {
      // inform user that only one permutation exists
  }
  ```
- This is a potential loss of data:

  ```
  int len = s.size();
  ```

  `size()` returns [`std::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), not `int`.  [Do not use `int` for `std::string` or other STL container sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int).  They have their own size types that prevents this very issue.  This would be the proper initialization of `len`:

  ```
  std::string::size_type len = s.size();
  ```
- This is needless and potentially dangerous:

  ```
  int* index = new int[len];
  ```

  The "dangerous" part refers to the fact that **`delete` is never used to free the allocated memory.  Always use `delete` with `new` where appropriate.**

  In order to free the memory properly, you would use `delete` in this way:

  ```
  delete [] index;
  ```

  But since you're utilizing the STL, instead consider an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

  ```
  std::vector<int> index(s.size());
  ```

  As the memory management is already properly done in `std::vector`'s implementation, `new`/`delete` is not needed here at all.  Always try to avoid doing this manually in C++.
- No need to pass the string's size; it's already part of the implementation.  Just use `s.size()`.
- With the utilization of the aforementioned `std::vector` and `size()`, you should now make `depth` and the loop counters of `std::size_t`.  This will avoid type-mismatch warnings from comparing `size()` with an `int`.  **Make sure your compiler's warning flags are high**.
- Avoid using `system("PAUSE")` as it is platform-specific and can be imitated by better alternatives such as `std::cin.get()`.  This will ask the user for a console *input* instead of a *keystroke*, but that difference shouldn't matter if it means maintaining portability.

Final code with applied changes (also tested on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QmPJZB)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void permutate(const std::string& s, std::vector<int>& index, std::size_t depth, int& count)
{
    if (depth == s.size())
    {
        ++count;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << s[index[i]];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        return;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    {
        index[depth] = i;
        permutate(s, index, depth+1, count);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("CBA");

    if (s.find_first_not_of(s.front()) == std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "Only 1 permutation exists";
        return 0;
    }

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());

    std::cout << s << "\n**********\n";

    std::vector<int> index(s.size());
    int count = 0;

    permutate(s, index, 0, count);

    std::cout << "\nTotal permutations with repetitions: " << count;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I think it could be improved by not calling the task "permutations".
Permutations are rearrangements.  It seems you are mostly producing all combinations.

I refer you to these:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: please elaborate,  this is for code review. please give a nice review of the code.

Comment: Whats to elaborate? Sure I have not give a full review of the code, but correct naming is an important part of coding and I thought qualifies as meaningful feedback. 'Permutation' not only generally means something other than as used in his code, but specifically means something else in C++, due to the standard library function next_permutation. And, btw, when I first looked at his code, one of the first things I wondered is why isnt he using std::next_permutation, and I had to figure out that he isn't doing perumtations. That's work for the next reader that could be avoided.

Comment: you put more into a comment explaining why you didn't add more to your answer.  point made. explain these things in the answer please.  as it stands your answer could have been written in a comment, and looks like a comment.

Comment: I have actually removed the `std::next_permutation` snippet from my answer.  I've realized that it may be best to stick with the OP's permutations with repetition, which the STL function does not perform.  Yes, permutations are rearrangements.  But the order *does* matter, unlike combinations.  I also agree with Malachi: your answer could be more substantial if it explained how the code can *actually* be improved.  If that means producing permutations *without* repetition, then that could be explained.  These links by themselves are not enough.